# PHP file downloads bytes missing

Tags: php

I'm trying to download an `.msi` file which it's actual size is 5.77 MB. When I execute the script the downloaded file will lose some bytes and will become 4.88 MB.

Code:

```
$file = 'apps/file.msi';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 5');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

I tried even with the anchor tag and the same happend. I also changed the extension from `.msi` to `.txt` and the bytes were also removed from the downloaded file.

I just can't figure it out

Comment: What are you using to measure the bytes before and after? This could just be different tools using different definitions of megabyte (1000*1000 vs 1024*1024)

Comment: I'm checking the properties of both files. The one on the server and the one downloaded. And I even opened both files in notepad++ and the original had more lines than the one downloaded.

Comment: The code is working fine on my local server. I think the problem is the hosting server. Maybe a directive in the ini file which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$file = 'apps/file.msi';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\""); 
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your server is configured to gzip the content transferred

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: Thank Paul you were right. I made the .msi file in a .rar file and everything is fine now.